# How to use test fixture in a parameterised test in XUnit

Tags: xunit2

I got these classes (which reads test files and which is to be tested in several different tests for different kinds of behavior):

```
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class TestFileFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public TestFileFixture()
        {
           ....
        }
        public IEnumerable<TestFile> AllTestFiles { get; } = new();
        <more properties>
    }

    [CollectionDefinition(CollectionName)]
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class TestFileCollectionFixture : ICollectionFixture<TestFileFixture>
    {
        // THE NAME OF THE FIXTURE
        public const string CollectionName = "Test Files";
        // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
        // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
        // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
    }

    public class TestFile
    {
        ...
    }
```

Which I am using as standard by adding this to the test classes:

```
[Collection(TestFileCollectionFixture.CollectionName)]
```

Which works fine.

However I have a test, which I want to parameterise over the files - one test for each file.
I have found no way to utilize MemberData or ClassData attributes for this.
Such as:

```
    [Theory]
    **[<Some attribute>(TestFileCollectionFixture.CollectionName))]**
    public void Given_GoodTestFiles_Expect_Parsed(TestFile testfile)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Is there a way to do this within the framework of XUnit?